# ADSi::setinfo() cant set the values in AD using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, com, active-directory

i am using c++ to interact with Active Directory server 2003...

```
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
V_BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"sanju");
V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;
hr = pIADsrootDSE->Put(L"myattrib",var );
hr = pIADsrootDSE->SetInfo();
```

this peace of code working,while it works(set values)in debugging time,after convert to exe & dll...
but these code cant work,when i will convert into package.
my logfile tells till Put() works fine...
my problem is setinfo() cant work in my package...

can anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Admin rights user cant set the value into Active Directory.